# In IE8 and IE9, a link inside a pop-up doesn't work

Tags: css, hyperlink, internet-explorer-8

I have a list that is shown as a pop-up when you click on an image.
The links inside the list don't work in IE9, but work in all other browsers. I suspect the pop-up loses its focus when the links inside it are clicked, but I can't find a workaround.

Please keep in mind that I don't want to use any JS for this, just CSS.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {display:none;}
ul li {list-style:none;}
a:focus + ul {display:block;}
ul:active {display:block;}
</style>

<a href="#" tabindex="200"><!--tabindex used for chrome & safari -->
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you
(Edited to remove the line that mentioned IE8 - it works fine there)

Comment: I think it's because your `ul` is hiding before the `a` is clicked as it is losing focus - [have a look at his in ie9](http://jsfiddle.net/QY3qy/2/)

Comment: Thank you Pete. I tried it and although the first link works fine, the other two behave strangely (e.g. when you click on either of them the other links dissapear and the link itself doesn't work). Do you experience the same?

Comment: The link worked for me but the other 2 did disappear. I thought that would've been ok though as if the link is followed then you would just load the New page anyway